# Wordpress 3.6, searchform.php problems

Tags: search

I have just updated to wordpress 3.6 and my theme seems to be ignoring my searchform.php file. Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: You might look at the answer [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/36-upgrade-searchformphp-not-working?replies=9#post-4487445).

Comment: Did you use the function in that post?

Comment: Yes, I edited the html within the function to match what my custom search form was!

Comment: @RoseCoder: So you are saying you edited your `functions.php` with the functions code suggested on the forum thread, and also used the `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` code into the block where you want to show the search form. AND then it's still not working, right? ...And what about using a get_template_part() instead of that include() on the bottom as: `<?php get_template_part('searchform',''); ?>`?

Comment: I edited the code in functions.php and used get_search_form() and it worked fine! I deleted searchform.php as it was no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is taken from WordPress.org Support Forum thread:
» [3.6 upgrade - searchform.php not working](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/36-upgrade-searchformphp-not-working?replies=9#post-4487445)

As [salcode](http://wordpress.org/support/profile/salcode) said:
Adding this code to your `functions.php` should do the trick:

```
function search_form_no_filters() {
  // look for local searchform template
  $search_form_template = locate_template( 'searchform.php' );
  if ( '' !== $search_form_template ) {
    // searchform.php exists, remove all filters
    remove_all_filters('get_search_form');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_search_form', 'search_form_no_filters');
```

And as from the experience from [RoseCoder](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/34375/rosecoder), you can remove the `searchform.php` *as it was no longer needed*.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress 3.6 `searchform.php` in your theme is still used by `get_search_form()`, unless is filtered out via `get_search_form` hook.

Sample code from get_search_form():

```
$search_form_template = locate_template( 'searchform.php' );
if ( '' != $search_form_template ) {
    ob_start();
    require( $search_form_template );
    $form = ob_get_clean();
} else {
    // compose the template, WordPress way
}

$result = apply_filters( 'get_search_form', $form );
if ( null === $result )
    $result = $form;

if ( $echo )
    echo $result;
else
    return $result;
```

Your problem was most likely generated by a faulty theme.